# Tree Not for sorting

Tags: tree, structure

Is there a way to organize data in a hierarchical manner without sorting?

for example I want to do a family tree which the grandfather is called "a" and the children are called "j" and "m" but the alphabetical order has nothing to do with who is the grandfather and grandson

this would be the ideal scenario would be this:

[image: example]

Comment: Yes of course you can organize data in trees without sorting - what concrete problem are you having? Also, which programming language is this

Answer (score 0):

If relation between elements has nothing to do with the content of element, then I don't think there is ready structure in java which fits your needs, but nothing stops you from writing it. I myself would base the solution on some kind `Node` class where

```
class Node<T> {
    private <T> value;
    private List<Node<T>> children;
    private Node<T> parent;
}
```

Add `getters` and `setters` as well as search/manage methods for tree and that's all you really need.